# Getting center DIV column into position between left and right floated columns?

Tags: html, css, youtube

I have been trying different ways of creating a three column CSS layout. On Youtube I found a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dRk_I5WtnuI) where this is achieved without a wrapper. I have been trying to float the "left" div column to the left, then the "content" div column (this comes second in the html code) to the right. The result according to the video is that the column which is not floated - in this case the "right" div column will automatically come up between the other two and the just needs a margin 0 auto to position it.

You can go to 4:20 onwards to see this in the video.

However, this is not happening for me. For some reason my "right" div column has a tendancy to wrap and end up elsewhere on the page - usually outside of the body area, and into the HTML background color. I know this can be solved by floating the "right" DIV column to the left, but I want to know why I can't achieve this as it is done in the video without my "right" div ending up half way down the page and outside of the body area.

The code is here

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>
Three Column!
</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
href="style.css" media="screen">
</head>
<body>



<div id="header">
<h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
</div>

<div id="left">
<p>
<ul>
<li>Here</li>
<li>There</li>
<li>Everywhere</li>
</ul>
</p>
</div>

<div id="content">
<p class="paragraphs">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut 
labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet 
clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur 
sadipscing elitr,  sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. 
At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum
dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,  sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore
et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. </p>
</div>

<div id="right">
<h2>Ad Content</h2>
<p class="Paragraphs">At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. 
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>

<div id="footer"><p>Footer</p></div>

</body>
</html>
```

and then the CSS

```
html, body 
{ 
        height : 100% ;
        margin : 0 ;
        padding : 0 
}

html { background : silver } 

body 
{ 
       background : black ;
       color : white ;
       height : 780px ;
       width : 1620px ;
       margin : 0 auto 2em ;
       font : 16px "Arial", sans-serif ;

}

#header 
{ 
         text-align : center ; 
         background : purple ;
         padding : 3px 0px ;
         margin : 100px 0 10px 
}

#left 
{ 
        float : left ;
        margin-right : 45px ;
        width : 180px ;
        height : 660px ;
        background-color : olive ;
        padding : 5px 
}

#content 
{ 
     float : right ;
     background-color : gray ; 
     height : 660px ; 
     width : 1140px ;
     padding : 5px 
}

#right 
{ 
       width : 180px ;
       background-color : blue ;
       height : 660px ;
       padding : 5px 
}

#footer 
{ 
       background-color : black ; 
       clear : both 
}

#footer p { text-align : center }
```

Comment: Please extract only the portion of code necessary for the question, and put them in a code snippet.

Comment: I take your point. I didn't know where exactly in the code I could have gone wrong, but will try to put up less code in future.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, if you remove width from the #right div, it seems to solve your problem. In this case, the #right div would take up the available space between the 2 divs. However, if you want to stick to the width you specified, give the #right div a display:inline-block;

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/beu3vcqn/)

```
#right 
{ 
   width : 180px ;
   background-color : blue ;
   height : 660px ;
   padding : 5px ;
   display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I can get these to work. The trouble is if I follow the example in the video  margin : o auto will not work for me even if I use the display : inline-block tag, although margin-left will work. I am not sure why that is. For sure your examples will get the job done, but I am baffled as to why margin : 0 auto does not work whatever I try.

Answer (score 0):

Using "div" and aligning them into different column floats are generally not a good idea in good responsive web design.

You should consider using a responsive grid system (or use the popular twitter bootstrap framework), you can read more at http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

It basically includes predefined classes for easy layout options, and in your case, you can set the following codes for your 3 floating column sections with something like this:

```
<!-- Column 1 -->    
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <p> Some content here </p>
    </div> 

<!-- Column 2 -->    
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <p> Some content here </p>
    </div> 

<!-- Column 3 -->    
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <p> your content here </p>
    </div>
```

You can then append extra margins and/or paddings CSS code to further customise the positioning of your column contents.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I have had a look at Bootstrap tutorials on Youtube. It looks interesting, but I feel I need to get a grasp of the basics first then work my way up.

Answer (score 0):

As a webdesigner I dont like my elements floating without control, its better just float them all in **left** and set width for each div. Please see the example below:

```css
html, body 
{ 
        height : 100% ;
        margin : 0 ;
        padding : 0 
}

html { background : silver } 

body 
{ 
       background : black ;
       color : white ;
       height : 780px ;
       width : 1620px ;
       margin : 0 auto 2em ;
       font : 16px "Arial", sans-serif ;

}

#header 
{ 
         text-align : center ; 
         background : purple ;
         padding : 3px 0px ;
         margin : 100px 0 10px 
}

#left 
{ 
        margin-right : 20px ;
        width : 180px ;
        height : 660px ;
        background-color : olive ;
        padding : 5px 
}

#content 
{ 
     background-color : gray ; 
     height : 660px ; 
     width : 1140px ;
     padding : 5px 
}

#right 
{ 
       width : 180px ;
       background-color : blue ;
       height : 660px ;
       padding : 5px 
}

#left, #content, #right {
    float: left;
}

#footer 
{ 
       background-color : black ; 
       clear : both 
}

#footer p { text-align : center }
```

```html
<title>
Three Column!
</title>
<body>



<div id="header">
<h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
</div>

<div id="left">
<p>
<ul>
<li>Here</li>
<li>There</li>
<li>Everywhere</li>
</ul>
</p>
</div>

<div id="content">
<p class="paragraphs">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut 
labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet 
clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur 
sadipscing elitr,  sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. 
At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum
dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,  sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore
et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. </p>
</div>

<div id="right">
<h2>Ad Content</h2>
<p class="Paragraphs">At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. 
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>

<div id="footer"><p>Footer</p></div>
    
</body>
```

a jsfiddle version is here http://jsfiddle.net/jx0qL9b6/2/